# Redirection through javascript inside a facebook iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, redirect, frame

I need to redirect inside a facebook application and then redirect back to the first page. This is all occuring within that facebook page and i need to tackle the facebook's iframe solution. I see that i will need to use `top.location` somehow. I cant figure out how.

**EDIT:** I have a facebook application. There is a link I want the user to go to and then come back on the current page. Since this is inside facebook's iframe, its hard to achieve through simple redirection.

Comment: I think that you might have to give a bit more detail to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can't you just use <a href="blah" target="_blank">link</a>?

Comment: It's still unclear what you are needing. I take it you don't mean to link to a new page within the iframe and then back to the original page still within the iframe, because that would be automatic using normal redirects. You already mentioned using `top.location` so I assume you want to "break out" of the iframe when following the link, but you already know the solution for that. Is the problem then getting "back into" the iframe? In that case you just need to redirect to apps.facebook.com/yourapp/yourpage to have Facebook reconstruct the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special. Use simple anchor tag to take user to another page:

```
<a href="/next-page.html">Come here</a>
```

And to take him back use javascript:

```
location.href = '/index.html';
```

That's all!